# Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment for google maps in forms

Tags: forms, xamarin

Please help with this problem in xamarin forms with custom render with layout inflate.

> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

C# code

```cs
base.OnElementChanged(e);

var mFRaFragment = this.Context as FragmentActivity;

_view = mFRaFragment.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.map_view, this, false);

mapFragment = mFRaFragment.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map);

// mapFragment = mFRaFragment.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map);

//mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance();
//Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mapFragment.ChildFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
//fragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.map, mapFragment);
////fragmentTransaction.Commit();
//fragmentTransaction.Detach(mapFragment).Attach(mapFragment).Commit();

mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: For Showing Map in xamarin forms getting this exception                                                                                       Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: I am curious why do you have the XML in your code but you should check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api)

Comment: i am using custom map with layout inflate

Comment: What i am asking you is why are you doing that what is the reason for this!

Comment: You might try not to use a `fragment tag` directly, instead use a `MapFragment MapFragment = MapFragment.NewInstance();` And  use `FragmentManager. BeginTransaction ().Add (Resource.Id.Framelayout, mapFragment).Commit ();` to add into the FrameLayout

Comment: could it work  ?